# Which of the following expresses the fact that the vectors $u$ and $v$ have the same length?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Which of the following expresses the fact that the vectors $u$ and $v$ have the same length?

(a) $u · u = v · v$

(b) $||u + v|| = ||u|| − ||v||$

(c) ${u \over||u||} = {v \over ||v||}$

(d) $||u + v|| = ||u|| + ||v||$

So my thoughts are, definitely not the last one or first. I think it would be b but it would be nice to get other opinions.

Comment: What is your basis for thinking the answer is (b)?  Why are you ruling out the first and last choices?  It is much easier to help you when you explain your thought process.

Comment: The first determines the similarity of the vectors and is dependant on the angles

And the last one is bad because if the vectors compliment each other then it is not true.

Comment: To help further your understanding, you might ask yourself which of the four equations expresses the fact that the vectors $u$ and $v$ have the same direction.  (A correct answer is among the four listed choices.)

Comment: Thanks Michael, would it be C in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the first because $u\cdot u$ is the length squared.

Comment: Hmmmm, can you explain a bit further? Why is C incorrect?

Comment: Because its the normalized vector, and has directions. Right but why does u*u make that the right answer? I see it could be the most probable out of the 4 but why is it right

Comment: $s\cdot s$ is the length squared. Therefore (a) tells us that s and v have the same length squared. Since the length is positive, you can take the square root and deduce that the length is the same.